# Cannot get the real author of a node through node_load() in drupal 7

Tags: nodes, database

this is a weird one... I have been using `node_load('NID')` for a few months now in my custom modules and it has always worked all right. The past two days however, something strange is going on. When I create a variable $node in which I load a specific node with node_load, it seems to do it (I can print the `$node` and all the details appear), EXCEPT that the `[uid]` of the node that is displayed in the print message is the uid of the logged-in user (if I masquerade as another user, that user's uid is shown). What is weird about all this is that in the database, the uid of the author of the node does not change at all.

```
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) $nodeid = arg(1);
    $node = node_load($nodeid);
    drupal_set_message('<pre>$node details '. print_r($node, TRUE) .'</pre>');
```

What the print message shows:

```
    $node details stdClass Object
    (
     [vid] => 480
     [uid] => 1
     [title] => test ad blocks 
     [log] => 
        [status] => 1
        [comment] => 1
        [promote] => 1
        [sticky] => 0
        [nid] => 116
        [type] => ads
        [language] => und
        [created] => 1434880742
        [changed] => 1434880742
        [tnid] => 0
        [translate] => 0
        [revision_timestamp] => 1434880742
        [revision_uid] => 59
    ...
```

But in the database, the uid is 59 for the node 116... 
This problem is recent, and the only aspects that have been modified are our custom modules which do not modify the nodes in any way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of working with arguments the way you do, try menu_get_object: [https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) Shall be more secure.

Comment: See revision_uid. You have revisions enabled, and user #1 seems to be the first user who created the node.

Comment: Hi Maen, I was actually using the menu_get_object, but it was doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: The database says otherwise... and anyway, I created yesterday that specific node under userid 59!

Comment: If there is something funky going on, try to replicate this on a clean install.

Comment: I just did, and it is the same... :-(